# Linux - Forcing 24-hour locale?

Tags: linux, date-time, locale

Is there any way to force 24-hour time in my locale (for example, 14:00) instead of 12-hour time (2:00 PM)?

I use the en_US locale with a UTF-8 character set on Arch Linux, but this shouldn't matter, I think.

Comment: What commands do you use that display a 12-hour time ?

Comment: @jlliagre: `strftime("%c")`, "preferred  date  and  time  representation  for the current locale", returns a 12-hour time value for en_US.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Locales can be set for various components separately, so you can set **`LC_TIME`** to either "**`en_GB.UTF-8`**" (Great Britain), "**`en_DK.UTF-8`**" (Denmark – ISO 8601 time), or "**`C`**" (no locale).

(Don't forget /etc/locale.gen.)

Comment: I have tried using en_GB.utf-8 for LC_TIME, but that has the unwanted side affect of swapping the position of the month and day in the short date format. Is there any way to JUST change the preference for 24 or 12 hour time?

Comment: @Thayne: I don't think so, no. (I use `en_DK.utf-8` myself.)

Comment: @ Thayne - I think you'd need to create and install a locale definition of your own, using `en_US` as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

As @grawity reports, you can try to find another locale for `LC_TIME`, but you will always have granularity problems, always compromising between options.  This is a known problem and I suggest that you add yourself to the following bug report: [Ubuntu Lauchpad bug #1392699](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1392699)

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: DavidPostill, I agree.  But until I have the reputation points, which might take years, I replied so at least users can be made aware of the problem.